# RESTful Paypal API WebHooks Simulator not working with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm developing an app using the `Paypal Api` and the `webhooks` simulator doesn't work. When I try to send an event, `Paypal` says it has been queued, `"Your event has been successfully queued at October 20 2015, 17:36:26"`, but when I try to debug it (using `Laravel`'s monolog) nothing shows up.
I am using https with third party certificate and the credentials work (I can create an order), do `webhooks` need any other configuration? Are they the only way to see the status of an order? The `Paypal` documentation is a little bit confusing...
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem!

It turns out that `Laravel` was stopping the request because of the `csrf protection`, since `Paypal`'s API request had no csrf token. disabling `csrf protection` on the URI of the webhook (this is done by placing the URI on the `$except` array of the `VerifyCsrfToken` class) solved it!